# Wild card routing without using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I just want to know how can we achieve wild card routing in pure `http.createServer` without using express.

in express we would do something like below

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var app = express();

app.get('/',function(req,red)
{
    res.send("I am foo");
});
app.get('/:id',function(req,res)
{
    res.send("I am Foo with id " + red.params.id);
});
```

but I wasn't able to find the equivalent in `http.createServer`

```
var http = require('http');

//create a server object:

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
 res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
 var url = req.url;
 if(url ==='/'){
    res.write('i am foo');
    res.end();
 }else if(url ==='/:id'){// 
    res.write('I am foo with id');
    res.end();
 }
}).listen(3000, function(){
 console.log("server start at port 3000");
});
```

one way we could achieve this is using pattern matching but I don't think its a feasible solution.

Comment: Any framework like express will use pattern matching, as you observed. You basically have to parse the path and implement any sort of special features (like wildcards and parameter extraction) yourself.

Comment: oh okay I did more research on parsing a path and it gave me a clear picture of how frameworks does the same, thanks for commenting!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945684/node-server-without-express-routing-how-to-use-path-parameters